# How can I fill a column with formulas from a range

Tags: excel, vba, range, copy-paste

```
With tblStueckpreis
    .ListColumns.Add position:=Application.Match(TABLEHEADERNAME, .HeaderRowRange, 0)
    ' Fügt die Formeln in die neue Staffel ein
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(tblStueckpreis.Range.Rows(1), "*Staffel*") <> 0 Then
        countHeader = Application.Match(TABLEHEADERNAME, .HeaderRowRange, 0) - 1
        For i = 1 To staffelRange.Rows.Count
            .DataBodyRange.Cells(i, countHeader) = staffelRange.Cells(i)
        Next
    End If
End With
```

> I try to copy the formulas from my range "staffelRange" and paste them into my table. 
>   Unfortunately I only get the values and not the formulas with my code. Pastespecial throws me an error, with Pastespecial I copied the range before and tried it with pastspecial. Unfortunately without success. Could someone please help me?

Comment: `.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, countHeader) = staffelRange.Cells(i)` is equivalent to `.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, countHeader).Value = staffelRange.Cells(i).Value`, so yes you'll only get the values that way.

Comment: then try with `Formula` property of `Range` object, instead of `Value` one

Comment: the Line: .DataBodyRange.Cells(i, countHeader) = staffelRange.Cells(i) doesnt work with staffelRange.Cells(i).Formulas :/

Comment: `.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, countHeader).Formula = staffelRange.Cells(i).Formula`? You may not need a loop either... but I suppose one of the formulas is not valid in the new table.

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 1 To staffelRange.Rows.Count
      .DataBodyRange.Cells(i, countHeader).Formula =staffelRange.Cells(i).Formula
Next
```